# How to install FIFA 14 on my phone?

Tags: games

How can I install FIFA 14 on my phone?

Any time I open the main file the phone tells me that there is no suitable program to open it; I have both the main file and the game

Comment: Where did you get the install from? Are you installing in the store?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply install FIFA 2014 by downloading it for free from the Microsoft Store, just [click here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/games/fifa-14/9wzdncrfj2v5).

You may want to try [FIFA 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/fifa-15-ut/9wzdncrdjpkp#app-details) as well.